# Topos quantum theory and distributive logic

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations

I am reading an introductory review on **topos quantum theory** https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5660 where in the motivation part it says (emphasis is mine):

> As we can see the non realism of standard quantum theory is a direct consequence of the fact that the logic of propositions is non-distributive. This, in turn, is a direct consequence of the way in which propositions are represented. Thus the *aim now is to find a topos analogue* for the mathematical constructs above, *which induces a distributive logic* on the collection of all propositions about a system.

I match this with my beliefs that the failure of logic to be distributive is an essential aspect of quantum theory, is supported by experimental evidence and connected with a number of deeply rooted concepts of quantum physics.

So now I am confused. Is my belief wrong? Is topos quantum theory considered a problematic area? How can I make sense of this motivation?

Why would one want to search for a distributive structure in connection with quantum theories?